# using python to show tcpdump content

Tags: python, tcpdump

I am new to python so I went to google to do a simple search and I got the below, I understand what the first two line of the code does (not really sure for the third line).

```
cmd1 = ['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-i', 'eth0']
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
fcntl.fcntl(p1.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
```

However, I want to use python to do an output of tcpdump information like how we do in the linux command prompt. Is it possible? because whenever I try to print out the content from p1 (based on the above command), I got some weird characters. I not sure where to go from after the first three lines of codes I have.

[image]

Comment: The `fcntl` call should not be necessary, as the operation `F_GETFL` should not have side effects (it returns information about the status of the file descriptor).

Comment: So in other words, just the first two lines of code should be sufficient? Then after that I will need to add a for loop to read each line and I can get the output similar to the screenshot? Thank you :D

Comment: There might still be problems with buffering (if it is not set to line-wise) but `Popen` has options to modify buffering. And yes, then you should be fine. As for the weird characters – that most probably has to do with a wrong encoding, but the behaviour you describe is pretty strange. I assume you know that you will have to read from `p1.stdout`.